# Magento2 LESS extend/override custom theme

Tags: magento2, css, less, grunt, extend

I have been going through research and tests for whole day and still found answers do not work for my case or I just do not understand how to properly implement them - therefore post here:

I have made a custom theme (**not** inheriting blank or luma; a standalone theme) in this path: `app/design/frontend/CompanyName/default`

And there I have css files (I am using grunt LESS) in this directory: `web/css`

There I have style files structured somewhat like this:

- `file1.less`

  - `dirA/file2.less`
  - `dirA/file3.less`

    - `dirA/dirB/file4.less`
  - `dirC/file5.less`

Each style file is `@import`'ing next file, so all of them are chained together. For example, `file1.less` has line `@import 'dirA/file2.less';` and so on.

I have added absolutely all less files to the `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` file, so that grunt know where and how to operate less files and generate css files.

With this theme everything is working just great.

Then I added another theme (which is child theme) in this path: `app/design/frontend/CompanyName/newDesign`. And it's parent theme is `app/design/frontend/CompanyName/default`;

Now I want to extend a css file in the child theme to change only one line, for example.

In `newDesign` theme I would like to extend less file which is located in this path of parent theme: `web/css/dirA/file3.less`.

**How should this be properly handled?**

As far as I understood, In child theme I have to create directory: `web/css/source`.

But what then? There should be only `_extend.less` file OR there I can make exactly the same folder and file structure as I have in the parent theme? - For example:

`app/design/frontend/CompanyName/newDesign/web/css/source/dirA/file3.less`

or it should be with `_extend.less` at the end, like this? -
`app/design/frontend/CompanyName/newDesign/web/css/source/dirA/file3_extend.less`

or I cannot make it like this at all? .., and I have to use only `app/design/frontend/CompanyName/newDesign/web/css/source/_extend.less` file?

In any solution that will come up here, I have another question, related to the `source` folder under `web/css`: which files from that folder I have to add to the `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` file of child theme properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set my themes up the following way, might not be the cleanest solution, but works like a charm.

In your `app/design/frontend/CompanyName/default/web/css/file1.less` add `@import '_extend.less';` at the bottom of the file.

Create 
 `app/design/frontend/CompanyName/default/web/css/_extend.less`
and
 `app/design/frontend/CompanyName/newDesign/web/css/_extend.less`

Leave the one in `app/design/frontend/CompanyName/default` empty. and make your changes in `app/design/frontend/CompanyName/newDesign/web/css/_extend.less`

---

For your question about the themes.js file.
As long as file1.less imports all of your other less files, you'll just have to add the following in your themes.js

```
default_theme: {
       area: 'frontend',
       name: 'CompanyName/newDesign',
       locale: 'en_US',
       files: [
          'css/file1'
       ],
       dsl: 'less'
    }
```

Comment: This means that absolutely each less file in default theme must have imported it's own separate empty _extend.less file if I want to update, for example, 1 line in each default theme .less file? Of course, we can live with one _extend.less file for whole theme, but it is exactly the same situation as we can live with only one .less file for whole theme. As You can see I have multiple .less files because it is easier to structure them this way. They each are imported in different levels and contexts. Therefore also this question about multiple _extend.less files. I hope You understood my point.

Comment: As far as I'm aware of it's either this or overwriting the entire file. I actually hope that I'm wrong but unfortunately I haven't found any other solutions yet. I'll stick along this topic to check if someone else might have a better solution :)

Comment: Thank You alot. Anyway, Your answer is correct because: all instructions on internet is shown related to the inheriting blank or luma theme and therefore there is already @import'ed the _extend.less file for some .less files. In my case, everything is custom built, therefore I have to create myself _extend.less file in parent theme, import into .less file and then I can use in child theme the _extend.less file. This is what did not work for me because I thought that Magento2 automatically can extend any .less file in parent theme through source dir but it is not that way. Thank You.